# How can I extract the zip code from the ggmap output?

Tags: r, geocoding, ggmap

```
structure(list(trip_count = 1:10, pickup_longitude = c(-73.964096, 
-73.989037, -73.934998, -73.93409, -73.998222, -74.004478, -73.994881, 
-73.955917, -73.993607, -73.948265), pickup_latitude = c(40.764141, 
40.760208, 40.746693, 40.715908, 40.750809, 40.741501, 40.74033, 
40.776054, 40.758625, 40.778515)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So I am trying to recode the longitude and latitude data into ZIP codes of NYC.
With `revgeocoding`from `ggmap` I already get some results:

```
res <- revgeocode(c(test$pickup_longitude[1],test$pickup_latitude[1]), output = "all")
```

However,

1. I can apply this procedure just to one location data at a time. Is there a way I can get the results for every location at once like

```
res <- revgeocode(c(test$pickup_longitude,test$pickup_latitude), output = "all")
```

2. How can I extract the ZIP Code from the ggmap results so that I can create a new column in the data frame with the correspondent zip code? Somehow the zip code is stored in a very strange way (see picture). How can I access this information in the console?[image]

The solutions does not have to work in `ggmap`, maybe there is a different approach to get the ZIP codes from the longitude and latitude data?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a sample output from `revgeocode`? I don't have an active API key.

Comment: `sapply(data.frame(t(df[2:3])), revgeocode, output='all')` should work. Although Probably `revgeocode` does take a matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an API key, but try something like the following:

```
my_func <- function(longlat, output){
  list(list(list(c(vector("list", 7), list(12345L)))))
}

test %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(zip = list(my_func(c(pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude), output = "all"))) %>% 
  mutate(zip = zip[[1]][[1]],
         zip = zip[[8]])
```

Replace `my_func` with `revgeocode` .  You'll have to figure out exactly how to pick out the zip code from the output.  But you can try something like the above.

Comment: Thanks Michael, unfortunatly I get:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `zip`.
x is.numeric(location) && length(location) == 2 is not TRUE
ℹ Input `zip` is `revgeocode(pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude, output = "all")`.
ℹ The error occurred in row 1.

Comment: Apparently, it is only possible to get one zip code at a time

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand the format of revgeocode.  Try my updated answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the Google API only allows one zip code at a time.  Your script can handle the iteration for you.

Comment: Hey Michael, that works quite well! You just have to put `list()`before `my_func`, However, this does not solve my second problem since this returns a list for every data point. I only need the zip but I do not know how this is stored within `revgeocode`

Comment: Use `dput` to post the output so far.

Comment: `dput`
 is way too much. But I edited the question and added a picture with the structure of the list object. Maybe this helps.

Comment: I obfuscated my sample function to give you an idea of how to pick out the bit you want.  You'll have to go by trial and error and slowly work your way there.

Comment: Hey Michael, if I do it the way you proposed I get the error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `zip`. Indexing outside the boundaries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224494/discussion-between-michael-dewar-and-max-s).